# Automatic GPS stopped getting locaton

Tags: android, android-service, android-location, android-gps

We are facing problem that is getting location from GPS frequently in background service but some times stopped location automatically in open area while I am sure that service is continuous running and do not effect deep sleep situation also in device idle mode. Please some body help.

```
 private void initLocationManager() {
    Log.e(TAG, "initializeLocationManager");
    if (mLocationManager == null) {
        mLocationManager = (LocationManager) 
 getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    }
    if (mLocationListeners == null) {
        mLocationListeners = new MyLocationListener();
        try {
            mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                    Constant.LOCATION_INTERVAL,
                    Constant.LOCATION_DISTANCE, mLocationListeners);
        } catch (SecurityException ex) {
            mLocationManager = null;
            mLocationListeners = null;
            WritingFile.getInstance().writeFile(Constant.ERROR_LOG, true, 
       AppManager.getInstance().getCurrentDateTime() + ex.getMessage() + 
       "20" + "\n");
            Log.i(TAG, "fail to request location update, ignore", ex);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            mLocationManager = null;
            mLocationListeners = null;
            WritingFile.getInstance().writeFile(Constant.ERROR_LOG, true, 
          AppManager.getInstance().getCurrentDateTime() + ex.getMessage() + 
        "21" + "\n");
            Log.d(TAG, "gps provider does not exist " + ex.getMessage());
        } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
            mLocationManager = null;
            mLocationListeners = null;
            WritingFile.getInstance().writeFile(Constant.ERROR_LOG, true, 
      AppManager.getInstance().getCurrentDateTime() + ex.getMessage() + "22" 
      + "\n");
            Log.d(TAG, "System Exception! Thread has no looper." + 
        ex.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            mLocationManager = null;
            mLocationListeners = null;
            WritingFile.getInstance().writeFile(Constant.ERROR_LOG, true, 
    AppManager.getInstance().getCurrentDateTime() + ex.getMessage() + "23" + 
    "\n");
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            mLocationManager = null;
            mLocationListeners = null;
            WritingFile.getInstance().writeFile(Constant.ERROR_LOG, true, 
      AppManager.getInstance().getCurrentDateTime() + ex.getMessage() + "24" 
       + "\n");
        }
    }

}

private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if (location == null) {
            //WritingFile.getInstance().writeFile(Constant.COORDINATE, true, AppManager.getInstance().getCurrentDateTime() + " NULL" + "\n");
            return;
        }
        //lastUpdatedTime = Constant.SIMPLE_DATE_FORMAT.format(location.getTime());
        if (location.getAccuracy() < 50) {
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
            // WritingFile.getInstance().writeFile(Constant.COORDINATE, true, lastUpdatedTime + " "+location.getLatitude() + ","+ location.getLongitude() + "AC"+ "\n");
        } else {
            if (latitude == 0.0 || longitude == 0.0) {
                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                longitude = location.getLongitude();
            }
            //WritingFile.getInstance().writeFile(Constant.COORDINATE, true, lastUpdatedTime + " "+location.getLatitude() + ","+ location.getLongitude() + "NON AC"+ "\n");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        switch (status) {
            case LocationProvider.AVAILABLE:
                //WritingFile.getInstance().writeFile(Constant.COORDINATE, true, AppManager.getInstance().getCurrentDateTime() + " AVAILABLE" + "\n");
                //WritingFile.getInstance().writeFile(Constant.COORDINATE, true, "Last Update Time" + lastUpdatedTime + "\n");
                break;
            case LocationProvider.OUT_OF_SERVICE:
                //WritingFile.getInstance().writeFile(Constant.COORDINATE, true, AppManager.getInstance().getCurrentDateTime() + " OUT_OF_SERVICE" + "\n");
                // WritingFile.getInstance().writeFile(Constant.COORDINATE, true, "Last Update Time" + lastUpdatedTime + "\n");
                removeLocationManager();
                mLocationManager = null;
                mLocationListeners = null;
                break;
            case LocationProvider.TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE:
                //WritingFile.getInstance().writeFile(Constant.COORDINATE, true, AppManager.getInstance().getCurrentDateTime() + " TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE" + "\n");
                //WritingFile.getInstance().writeFile(Constant.COORDINATE, true, "Last Update Time" + lastUpdatedTime + "\n");
                removeLocationManager();
                mLocationManager = null;
                mLocationListeners = null;
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        //WritingFile.getInstance().writeFile(Constant.COORDINATE, true, AppManager.getInstance().getCurrentDateTime() + " PROVIDER ENABLEE" + "\n");
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        //WritingFile.getInstance().writeFile(Constant.COORDINATE, true, AppManager.getInstance().getCurrentDateTime() + " PROVIDER DISABLE" + "\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: where's your code?

Comment: Please add your code snippet here. Without that its very difficult to understand the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

```
 private void initLocationManager() {
        Log.e(TAG, "initializeLocationManager");
        if (mLocationManager == null) {
            mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        }
        if (mLocationListeners == null) {
            mLocationListeners = new MyLocationListener();
            try {
                mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                        Constant.LOCATION_INTERVAL,
                        Constant.LOCATION_DISTANCE, mLocationListeners);
            } catch (SecurityException ex) {
                mLocationManager = null;
                mLocationListeners = null;
                WritingFile.getInstance().writeFile(Constant.ERROR_LOG, true, AppManager.getInstance().getCurrentDateTime() + ex.getMessage() + "20" + "\n");
                Log.i(TAG, "fail to request location update, ignore", ex);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
                mLocationManager = null;
                mLocationListeners = null;
                WritingFile.getInstance().writeFile(Constant.ERROR_LOG, true, AppManager.getInstance().getCurrentDateTime() + ex.getMessage() + "21" + "\n");
                Log.d(TAG, "gps provider does not exist " + ex.getMessage());
            } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
                mLocationManager = null;
                mLocationListeners = null;
                WritingFile.getInstance().writeFile(Constant.ERROR_LOG, true, AppManager.getInstance().getCurrentDateTime() + ex.getMessage() + "22" + "\n");
                Log.d(TAG, "System Exception! Thread has no looper." + ex.getMessage());
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                mLocationManager = null;
                mLocationListeners = null;
                WritingFile.getInstance().writeFile(Constant.ERROR_LOG, true, AppManager.getInstance().getCurrentDateTime() + ex.getMessage() + "23" + "\n");
            } catch (Throwable ex) {
                mLocationManager = null;
                mLocationListeners = null;
                WritingFile.getInstance().writeFile(Constant.ERROR_LOG, true, AppManager.getInstance().getCurrentDateTime() + ex.getMessage() + "24" + "\n");
            }
        }

    }

    private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            if (location == null) {
                //WritingFile.getInstance().writeFile(Constant.COORDINATE, true, AppManager.getInstance().getCurrentDateTime() + " NULL" + "\n");
                return;
            }
            //lastUpdatedTime = Constant.SIMPLE_DATE_FORMAT.format(location.getTime());
            if (location.getAccuracy() < 50) {
                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                // WritingFile.getInstance().writeFile(Constant.COORDINATE, true, lastUpdatedTime + " "+location.getLatitude() + ","+ location.getLongitude() + "AC"+ "\n");
            } else {
                if (latitude == 0.0 || longitude == 0.0) {
                    latitude = location.getLatitude();
                    longitude = location.getLongitude();
                }
                //WritingFile.getInstance().writeFile(Constant.COORDINATE, true, lastUpdatedTime + " "+location.getLatitude() + ","+ location.getLongitude() + "NON AC"+ "\n");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            switch (status) {
                case LocationProvider.AVAILABLE:
                    //WritingFile.getInstance().writeFile(Constant.COORDINATE, true, AppManager.getInstance().getCurrentDateTime() + " AVAILABLE" + "\n");
                    //WritingFile.getInstance().writeFile(Constant.COORDINATE, true, "Last Update Time" + lastUpdatedTime + "\n");
                    break;
                case LocationProvider.OUT_OF_SERVICE:
                    //WritingFile.getInstance().writeFile(Constant.COORDINATE, true, AppManager.getInstance().getCurrentDateTime() + " OUT_OF_SERVICE" + "\n");
                    // WritingFile.getInstance().writeFile(Constant.COORDINATE, true, "Last Update Time" + lastUpdatedTime + "\n");
                    removeLocationManager();
                    mLocationManager = null;
                    mLocationListeners = null;
                    break;
                case LocationProvider.TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE:
                    //WritingFile.getInstance().writeFile(Constant.COORDINATE, true, AppManager.getInstance().getCurrentDateTime() + " TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE" + "\n");
                    //WritingFile.getInstance().writeFile(Constant.COORDINATE, true, "Last Update Time" + lastUpdatedTime + "\n");
                    removeLocationManager();
                    mLocationManager = null;
                    mLocationListeners = null;
                    break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            //WritingFile.getInstance().writeFile(Constant.COORDINATE, true, AppManager.getInstance().getCurrentDateTime() + " PROVIDER ENABLEE" + "\n");
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            //WritingFile.getInstance().writeFile(Constant.COORDINATE, true, AppManager.getInstance().getCurrentDateTime() + " PROVIDER DISABLE" + "\n");
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is not answer. You can just update question to indicate your code.

Comment: actually I am new in stackoverflow that is why some thing is missing but this is my code block